# emergency brake on while driving

Tags: emergency-brakes

I just had my front brakes and rotorers replaced and did not realize that my emergency brake was on.  I had drove like maybe 60 miles before I goggled why it was on.  I am a first time driver so my question is do I have to have the car checked again?  I did not smell anything burning or anything that I thought was unordinary.  I just want to be safe! I guess we all learn by our mistakes but I son't want this to be an expensive mistake on my part.

Thank you